# How do I land a building precisely to connect to a techlab/reactor in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran

When I am doing the swap-around, how can I be sure to land the building at the precise location to connect to the reactor or the tech-lab?

I see pros do it seamlessly, but when I do it, I have to lift-off and re-land multiple times till I make it connect successfully, and that by luck.

Is there an indicator that shows me the spot to land to connect to a building extension **before** I land?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The UI of Starcraft 2 should show you an outline of the building after you have hit the land command. This outline will allow you to place the building correctly.

When you invoke the land option, you will see two outlines: one where your mouse is and one beside the tech tab/reactor:

[image: Outline after invoking the land command.]

Simply move your mouse so that the outlines overlap:

[image: Lining up the mouse outline with the outline next to the add-on.]

Then, click the left mouse button. Your building will start flying toward the target location:

[image: Building heading toward the landing zone.]

If you lined everything up correctly, it will land right beside the add-on:

[image: Building after landing beside the add-on.]

Comment: very nice, its good to note the addon will 'light up' when it is successfully connected :)  I love pictures!

Comment: The ghost-image overlapping part did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Have you turned grid on in options?
Other than that, there's not much to do... practice maybe. I never had any problems with that, myself.

Answer (score 2):

When your building is lifted and selected, it will outline the optimum 'landing zone' to marry up to an un-utilized add-on.  The add-on must always be on the right of a building, this is true for all buildings.

Try turning on the building options if this isn't already enabled for you (perhaps building grid?)  There is still a little art in successful landing, but the guide can help a ton.

Hope this helps!